# React - Native : What is the difference between Synthetic Touch Events locationX and pageX

Tags: react-native

when ever the `View` is touched,position of the `View` can be tracked down by using `Synthetic Touch Events`.According to [Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view#synthetic-touch-events),

```
locationX - The X position of the touch, relative to the element.

pageX - The X position of the touch, relative to the root element.
```

I do not really understand the different between them. I have to render a `View` over the page where page is touched.

So, Which is better one to consider `locationX` or `pageX`? And also please let me know the difference between them?

Comment: Lets say you have a View positioned on as screen at (10,10) coordinates.
When you click at the top-left corner of the View, relatively to View that would be coordinate (1,1). But relatively to screen that would be (11,11). First one is locationX, second is pageX.